# USB hard disk not working after plugging it into Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I plugged my USB (Sandisk cruzer 16 gb) into my dual boot computer which contains windows 10 and Ubuntu.

After I unplugged it, the USB no longer shows up.

I thought it was a problem with Ubuntu so I tried it on windows, but in windows it pops up for just one second and then disappears.

It doesn't show up on my smart TV either.

I then ignored it because it was an old USB and I didn't have any important files on it.

Then yesterday I plugged in my 1 TB external hard disk ([this one](https://www.amazon.in/Toshiba-Canvio-Basics-External-Drive/dp/B00N78RZO6)) and copied some files and then removed it.

Now it as same as the USB. The same stuff all over again. It had lot of files in it. It is same as before, not showing up on any OS.

Some of the articles online show that (for windows 10) I should update its driver in device manager. Just like before, It shows up on the device manager for just a second

If I use the command `sudo lsusb` it doesn't show my USB,but if i use the same command immediately after I plug in my USB it shows `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer` but it disappears after you type the command again

If I open the logs using `dmesg` it shows

```
[ 8285.607056] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd 

[ 8286.514853] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 11 

[ 8286.522727] scsi 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
```

Comment: Did you unmount the disk properly before unplugging it? If not, chances are that the filesystem on disk has been damaged and it needs to be reformatted. However, in that case it should still be visible as a device, even if data on it is not accessible. Type `sudo lsusb` in the terminal after plugging in your disk and see if the disk is visible in the list.

Comment: @raj No i tried `sudo lsusb` but it dosent show up

Comment: @raj But if you use that command immediately after you plugged it then it shows `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer` . But if you use that command again it doesn't show up

Comment: That's strange, like the device is unplugging itself right after you plug it in. I can't think of a reason for it. Is there something in the logs? Type `dmesg` and look for messages about USB devices connection and disconnection.

Comment: @raj This is interesting this is the log `[ 8285.607056] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 8286.514853] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 8286.522727] scsi 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device`

Comment: @raj BTW the hard disk is showing up on the terminal after using lsusb, it shows `Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0480:a202 Toshiba America Inc Canvio Basics HDD
`

Comment: This is the log form hard disk `[ 8398.137499] usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 8398.287800] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a202, bcdDevice= 3.15
[ 8398.287812] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8398.287819] usb 1-10: Product: External USB 3.0
[ 8398.287823] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[ 8398.287827] usb 1-10: SerialNumber: 20151026009191F`

Comment: @raj the rest of the log `[ 8398.289371] usb-storage 1-10:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 8398.289818] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-10:1.0
[ 8420.185573] usb 1-10: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that hard disk (Toshiba) works, but the USB Stick (Cruzer) does not? The message `rejecting I/O to dead device` might mean that the USB Stick got physically damaged. Hard disk, on the other hand, might require reformatting. Check also `sudo lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l` to check if any partitions are visible on the hard disk. Also, I would suggest to have the computer checked by a technician, if there isn't any hardware problem with the USB ports that damages devices connected to that machine.

Comment: Please [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1359879/edit) with all the new information you put in the comments. The comments are our channel to ask for information. You should edit your question.